# A star in a URL breaks the linkification in posts

Tags: bug, status-completed, hyperlinks

I wanted to add a link containing "A*" to an answer. It had the link at the bottom and I wondered why he didn't link to A* normally.
But when I tried it wouldn't show up as a URL in the preview, so I guess that's why it was added as plain text in the answer instead.

This is the link: `http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A*_search_algorithm`.

Comment: What about this link: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13484159/32453 should I start a new question post?

Comment: See also: http://meta.webapps.stackexchange.com/q/2254/24166

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's like magic!

[A* Search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A%2A_search_algorithm)

Comment: Thanks for wikiing it (is that a word?) so I could see the magic.

Comment: It seemed the easiest way :-)

Answer (score 4):

This works OK so long as you don't try to do it "raw":

```
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A*_search_algorithm
```

won't work, whereas

```
[link][1]

  [1]: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A*_search_algorithm
```

or

```
[link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A*_search_algorithm)
```

will: [link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A*_search_algorithm), [link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A*_search_algorithm).

Comment: In comments, the third example does not work: [link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A*_search_algorithm) versus the version with `%2A`, [link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A%2A_search_algorithm). See [Star in link(s) in comments is removed](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/108726/star-in-links-in-comments-is-removed/).

Comment: so is this a  bug or not? it seems like it should parse a star as a continuation of the url... http://stackoverflow.com/a/1547940/32453